# Flutter: How do I show a clock that includes milliseconds?

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app with Flutter and I need to show a clock that includes milliseconds

Here's what I have so far. It works, but only shows seconds.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _timeString = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 50), (Timer t) => _getTime());
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getTime() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
    setState(() {
      _timeString = formattedDateTime;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, using `'hh:mm:ss:SS'` is enough.